# What is this code doing with pointers?

Tags: delphi, pointers, casting

I still don't have a good understanding of how pointers work in Delphi. While reviewing a library of mine, in a function I use commonly called `GetIPAddress` (used to get local machine's IP address), I came across a strange cast using pointers (line marked below). I didn't write this, but found it somewhere a while back...

```
uses
  Winsock;

function GetIPAddress: string;
type
  pu_long = ^u_long;
var
  varTWSAData: TWSAData;
  varPHostEnt: PHostEnt;
  varTInAddr: TInAddr;
  namebuf: array [0 .. 255] of ansichar;
begin
  try
    try
      if WSAStartup($101, varTWSAData) <> 0 then Result := ''
      else begin
        gethostname(namebuf, sizeof(namebuf));
        varPHostEnt := gethostbyname(namebuf);
        varTInAddr.S_addr := u_long(pu_long(varPHostEnt^.h_addr_list^)^); //<--- ???
        Result := WideString(inet_ntoa(varTInAddr));
      end;
    except
      Result := '';
    end;
  finally
    WSACleanup;
  end;
end;
```

What exactly is happening here with the pointers?

Comment: The error checking is a mess here, fwiw. WSACleanup called in the wrong place. No error checking on gethostname or gethostbyname. Really needs to be fixed.

Comment: FWIW, a shameless plug of an article that might help understand pointers: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html ("Addressing Pointers").

Comment: That had to be parked elsewhere. That site is currently not under my control, so use http://praxis-velthuis.de/rdc/articles/articles-pointers.html instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PHostEnt` is a pointer to a [`hostent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738552%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a type defined in the Windows API.  h_addr_list is an array of PAnsiChar values that's really an array of bytes (in C, a char and a byte are the same thing, which complicates C APIs dealing with byte buffers).

What this is saying:

- varPHostEnt^: dereference the pointer to the hostent
- h_addr_list^: dereference the pointer to the array of byte arrays, getting the first member
- pu_long cast: interpret the first member (a byte array pointer) as a ulong pointer
- pu_long()^: dereference this pointer and get the ulong it points to
- ulong cast: unnecessary, as we're already dealing with a ulong
- S_addr := The in_addr record is a variant type that can be interpreted as either a uint32 (4-byte unsigned integer) or as an array of 4 individual bytes.  Assign this ulong (4-byte unsigned integer) to the former interpretation.

Comment: Don't get that rollback... Remy's explanation what `h_addr_list` type really is was accurate. Now you've got it wrong again. It's not `array of PAnsiChar` as you state. [no voting here]

Comment: @TLama: That's how it's defined Delphi-side.  (Well, actually as a ^PAnsiChar.)  My explanation makes sense of it, rather than confusing matters further by explaining something that is different from what a coder using Delphi is going to see.

Comment: Bad rollback. Remy was correct. This answer as it stands is incorrect!

Comment: @Danny: Feel free to look up the definition in winsock.pas.